# How can I use ngAnimate with ngTable?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate, ngtable

Check out this plnkr where I'm trying to combine both ng-animate and ng-table:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EfZF5oWb9qzGvOIbAhtX?p=preview

As you can see, I have injected both directives into the scope, and I have the CSS for the animations in style.css, but for some reason there isn't any animations happening... anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? (There isn't any errors in the console currently) Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation class should be put on the same element as the `ngRepeat` directive:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in $data" class="animate">
```

Comment: Theoretically this should work, but I don't see it working. I am facing the same problem. I tried with ngFx, animate.css or custom animations, but the results is always the same: when I filter the results, there is no animation.

Comment: Able to replicate it in a Plunker or JSFiddle? If so I will take a look.